# I have 3 fragments, I am using viewpager2, tablayout, I want to integrate Navigation component in this

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm building a chatting app in Kotlin and I've created an adapter that's hooked up to a view pager and tab layout. I can swipe through the different fragments, but I'm also using the navigation component and I'm unsure how to use its actions to navigate between the fragments. My NavHostFragment Container is causing trouble - should I place it in the same layout file as the view pager and tab layout? As I populate the fragments with views, I'll need to use the navigation component to navigate or listen to click events, but the view pager is interfering with the navigation controller. Can you please advise me on where to place the NavHostFragment and how to handle click event listeners or use the navigation component for navigating between the fragments? My goal is to keep the swiping functionality for navigating between the fragments while also allowing the use of the navigation component to navigate by clicking

MyPagerAdapter.kt

```
`class MyPagerAdapter(
fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
lifecycle: Lifecycle,
private val fragments: List<Pair<String, Fragment>>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle)  {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position].second
}

fun getPageTitle(position: Int): String {
    return fragments[position].first
}
```

}`

ViewPagerHome.kt (The layout which is hooked to this file, has viewpager, and here I intend to add my NavHostFragment as well)

```
`class ViewPagerHome : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_home)




    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.vPTL)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)



    tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.vpTabLayout)
    viewPager2 = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager2)


    val fragmentList = listOf(
        Pair("Recent Chat", RecentChats()),
        Pair("Users", UsersFragment()),
        Pair("Setting", SettingFragment())
    )


    val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle, fragmentList)

    viewPager2.adapter = adapter

    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW)


    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2) { tab, position ->
        // Set the text for each tab
        tab.text = adapter.getPageTitle(position)
    }.attach()


}`
```

activity_viewpager_home.xml (here if I decrease the height of view pagerI am afraid then I will not be able to swipe through whole screen, so where do I put the navhostfragment?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ViewPagerHome">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/vPTL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/vpTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicator="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">







</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>







</LinearLayout>`
```

I tried setting NavController and refering the Navhost fragment with id in the ViewPagerHome.kt activity.

I tried setting buttons on individual fragments to see if I could navigate to other fragment (as my navgraph has actions defined already)

Is there a way to set Navigation action in view pager adapter?